# Number of temperature controlled storage units

Tags: graph-theory

> Use graph theory to model and describe the following problem's solution. Suppose $C = \{c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n\}$ is a collection of chemicals which must be stored very carefully at very specific temperatures.
>
> For each $c_i \in C$, you know that the lowest temperature at which it can be stored, call it $l_i$, and highest temperature at which it can be stored, call it $h_i$.
>
> Determine the smallest number of temperature-controlled storage units into which the chemicals can be stored.

I am not too familiar with graph theory, if you could help direct me to the proper type of graph that is to be used for this problem that would be greatly appreciated. This problem is hard for me to wrap my head around as it deals with a number of chemicals from $1$ to $n$, which could potentially be infinite.

Comment: How do you mean "a number of chemicals from $1$ to $n$, which could potentially be infinite"? There are finitely many numbers from $1$ to $n$. Perhaps you mean that there is no finite bound on the finite number $n$?

Comment: Anyway, you can have the chemicals as vertices and have an edge between two chemicals if they can be stored at a common temperature; then the chemicals in a storage unit must form a clique in the resulting graph, and the minimal number of storage units is the minimal number of disjoint cliques that contain all vertices. I don't know if this problem of decomposition into cliques is tractable; some clique problems are NP-complete; see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Listing_all_maximal_cliques).

Answer (score 1):

This is no graph theory problem—it can be formulated as follows:

> You have a number of wooden planks which start and end at real numbers $s_i$'s and $e_i$'s. How many nails do you need so that each plank is hit by a nail?

or

> You have a number of intervals on $\mathbb{R}$, how many points do you need so that for each interval there is a point within its scope.

**Hint:**

- Consider the the smallest highest temperature for any chemical. Your container that will hold that chemical has to have temperature not larger than that.
- However, there is no point in making it even smaller, because there is no chemical of smaller highest storage temperature.
- Once you have the first temperature set, without loss of generality you can put in that container all the chemicals that could be stored in there.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$